Dedot Flipper contract flip() operation not working
I am trying to work with the default flipper contract with react js based on the link: https://github.com/dedotdev/dedot.
I am trying to follow the Submitting transactions section.
First of all, I am not sure if I should use the address of ALICE as a parameter for signAndSend or if I should use keyring.
Second, the if statement isn't satisfying for me as the status types are different.
The code is:
useEffect(() => {
    const initializeContract = async () => {
      try {
        await cryptoWaitReady();
        const keyring = new Keyring({ type: "sr25519" });
        const alice = keyring.addFromUri("//Alice");

        setAlicePair(alice);

        const client = await DedotClient.new(new WsProvider(WS_URI));
        const contractInstance = new Contract(
          client,
          contractAbi,
          CONTRACT_ADDRESS
        );
        setContract(contractInstance);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to initialize contract:", error);
      }
    };

    initializeContract();
  }, []);

Note, the useEffect is running fine.
The code to query flip is:
  const handleFlip = async () => {
    if (!contract) return;

    try {
      const { data, raw } = await contract.query.flip({ caller: ALICE });

      if (data.isErr) {
        console.log("Cannot make transaction due to error:", data.err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(data, raw);

      await contract.tx
      .flip({ gasLimit: raw.gasRequired })
      .signAndSend(alicePair, ({ status, events }) => {
        if (status.type === 'BestChainBlockIncluded' || status.type === 'Finalized'){
          console.log("Transaction status:", status.type);

          // Log all events for debugging
          events.forEach(({ event }) => {
            console.log(`Event: ${event.section}.${event.method}`, event.data.toHuman());
          });

          const flippedEvent = events.find(({ event }) => event.method === 'Flipped');
          if (flippedEvent) {
            console.log("Old value:", flippedEvent.event.data.old);
            console.log("New value:", flippedEvent.event.data.new);
          } else {
            console.log("Flipped event not found in transaction events.");
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Transaction status:", status.type);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Flip operation failed:", error);
    }
  };

In this case I am getting the log:
Transaction status: Validated
Transaction status: Broadcasting

clearly, the if statement isn't satisfying the condition and I am getting the log from:
console.log("Transaction status:", status.type); part.
Here is the flip implementation at the smart contract:
#[ink(event)]
        pub struct Flipped {
            #[ink(topic)]
            pub old: bool,
            #[ink(topic)]
            pub new: bool,
        }

#[ink(message)]
        pub fn flip(&mut self) {
            let old_value = self.value;
            self.value = !self.value;

            // Emit the event
            self.env().emit_event(Flipped {
                old: old_value,
                new: self.value,
            });
        }

Note, that the handler function for the get() query is working fine. So there is no problem with the contract or its ABI.
Please let me know where I am wrong with the flip handler. I appreciate any help you can provide.

What is the contracts rpc node that you're connecting to? From issue that you're getting into, I guest you might be using a local substrate-contracts-node at https://127.0.0.1:994. Currently, the local substrate-contracts-node (v0.41.0) does not work fine/comply with the latest changes in new JSON-RPC APIs via DedotClient, you might want to try the LegacyClient. So just replace DedotClient with LegacyClient then things should be fine to you!
import { LegacyClient, WsProvider } from 'dedot';

// initialize the connection using LegacyClient
const client = await LegacyClient(new WsProvider(WS_URI));

You can also try to generate the Types & APIs for the contracts using your contract metadata (ABI) (.json or .contract) file, and apply the ContractApi interface when initializing the Contract instance, it'll enable auto-completion/IntelliSense when you working with the contract APIs.
Please follow the below steps:

Generate the Types & APIs for the contract using dedot cli
Using the generated FlipperContractApi to when initialize the Contract instance

const contract = new Contract<FlipperContractApi>(client, contractAbi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

const { data: state } = await contract.query.flip({ caller: ALICE });

console.log('Boolean state:', state)
// ...

